# How to create an instance that belongs to an interface and implement it

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm currently learning Java so please bear with my ignorance. Here is my current code

**Shape.java**

```
public interface Shape {
    public abstract void draw();
}
```

**Rectangle.java**

```
public abstract class Rectangle implements Shape {

    private final double width, length;

    public Rectangle() {
        this(1,1);
    }
    public Rectangle(double width, double length) {
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("A rectangle of sides " +  length + " by " + width + " will be drawn");
    }

}
```

**TestPolymorph.java**

```
public class TestPolymorph implements Shape {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape[] drawObject = { new Rectangle(40, 60) };
        drawObject[0].draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Is there anything wrong with my current code since it's not working. My question is how can I  create a `drawObject` instance that belongs to `Shape` class and during runtime `drawObject`will be created with two arguments, length and width (giving 40 and 60 for example), draw method of `Rectangle` will then be invoked.

Comment: can you elaborate "not working"? giving exceptions or not printing what you expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close, there really isn't any need to have your TestPolymorph implement Shape.  That is your driver, not a model implementing an interface so you could take that off.

Lastly, remove the abstract from the Rectangle class.  That is not an abstract class because you actually want an instance of that type.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the `abstract` modifier from the `Rectangle` object.  You also don't need to implement the `Shape` interface in `TestPolymorph.java`

Comment: @Vui La Chinh Yes seems like problem in `abstract` modifier.you can not  instantiate obj in abstract class.if you want to create abj you have to use anonymous class implementation.

Answer (score 2):

```
Shape[] drawObject = { new Rectangle(40, 60) };
```

above is your code

```
Shape[] drawObject = { new Rectangle(40, 60) {} };
```

this is correct code

since you are creating `objects of abstract` class you have to go with this 
 approach. or you can just `remove abstract modifier` from `Rectangle class`

if you are creating a object of abstract class you are forced to implement all its abstract methods , since you dont have any abstract method inside your abstract rectangle class you just have to `new Rectangle(40, 60) {}`
pass empty brackets at the end bt if your class has abstract methods inside the brackets you have to implement the abstract method

Comment: Or since there appears no reason for Rectangle to be abstract, perhaps a better solution would be to just make it concrete.  It seems unlikely that anonymous inner classes are a topic that this beginner is prepared for or presently interested in.

Answer (score 0):

1. Improving Interface

Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public and abstract.

Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple. Rather than complicating the things.
Just go in a valid inherited manner.
Remove the abstract from Rectangle class and also there is no need for TestPolymorph to implement the Shape interface.
Rectangle implements the Shape interface and just Test Polymorphism in TestPolymorph.